# How to increase a cell height by animation in objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableviewcell which i want to make it big by tapping on it . I am able to make it big if i tap and get back to normal height when i tap it once again , but the transition isnt good . Is there a way when i tap on cell the transition is smooth and the cell height becomes big .

```
-(void) zoomInProperties
{
        remedyTextLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        CGSize maximumLabelSize=CGSizeMake(270.0,100.0);
        CGSize expectedLabelSize=[remedyTextLabel.text sizeWithFont:remedyTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                      lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        NSLog(@"Height=%f",expectedLabelSize.height);
        NSLog(@"Width=%f",expectedLabelSize.width);

        if (expectedLabelSize.height>17 || expectedLabelSize.width > 260.0)
        {
            CGRect newFrame= remedyTextLabel.frame;
            newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
            newFrame.origin=CGPointMake(43.0,24.0);
            remedyTextLabel.numberOfLines=(expectedLabelSize.height/17);
            remedyTextLabel.frame= CGRectMake(43.0, 24.0, 270.0, expectedLabelSize.height);
            blackRemedyTxtImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 13.0, 320.0,expectedLabelSize.height+13.0);
            remedyImage.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 75.0, 320.0,83.5);
            remedyLabel.frame=CGRectMake(27.0, 85.0,183.0,58.0);

            notifyMe.frame = CGRectMake(350.0, 69.0, 66.0, 33.0);

            backgroundCellImage.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0,130.5);
            RemedyCustomCellView.frame=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, 320.0, 136.5);
        }

    }


}

//  ZoomOutProperties  Method
-(void) zoomOutProperties
{
        NSLog(@"zoom out");

        remedyTextLabel.numberOfLines=1;
        remedyTextLabel.frame=CGRectMake(43.0,22.0 ,270.0,17.0);
        remedyTextLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        remedyTextLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
        remedyImage.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 46.0, 320.0, 83.5);
        remedyLabel.frame=CGRectMake(27.0,55.0 ,183.0,58.0);
        blackRemedyTxtImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 13.0, 320.0,30.5);
        backgroundCellImage.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0,129.5);
        RemedyCustomCellView.frame=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, 320.0, 129.5);
        notifyMe.frame = CGRectMake(350.0, 69.0, 66.0, 33.0);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` back-to-back the table view will recalculate all cell heights and animate any size changes:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Just remember that any calls to `reloadData`, `insertSections:withRowAnimation:`, `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, etc. before the resize animation finishes can conflict with the animation in progress.

Comment: the above method is used in custom tableviewcell file ..I am using heightForRowAtIndexPAth in my mainviewcontroller file

Comment: the above method in the sense the code which i have added is in custom cell file...should i add beginupdates in heightforrowatindexpath in mainviewcontroller file

Comment: You should call it from a delegate method or notification handler that results from the cell wanting to expand.  Putting it in `heightForRow` is a bad idea because it will most likely go into an infinite loop.

Comment: when i call `beginupdates` ..i should still use my original code right

Comment: I would let the `UITableViewCell` rely on autosizing or Auto Layout to configure itself for its new bounds and then control the actual height value in `heightForRow`.  If you needed, you can also set a `isExpanded` flag on the cell to use in `layoutSubviews`.